# Convert column with string json string to column with dictionary in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a column with following structure in my dataframe.

```
+--------------------+
|                data|
+--------------------+
|{"sbar":{"_id":"5...|
|{"sbar":{"_id":"5...|
|{"sbar":{"_id":"5...|
|{"sbar":{"_id":"5...|
|{"sbar":{"_id":"5...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The data inside column is a json string. I want to convert the column to some other type (map, struct..). How do I do this with a udf function? I have created a function like this but cant figure out what the return type should be. I tried StructType and MapType which threw error. This is my code.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StructType

udf_getDict = F.udf(lambda x: json.loads(x), StructType)

subset.select(udf_getDict(F.col('data'))).printSchema()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an approach with `spark.read.json` and `df.rdd.map` such as this:

```
json_string = """
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"""
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, json_string), 
    ],
    ['id', 'txt'] 
)
df2.dtypes
[('id', 'bigint'), ('txt', 'string')]


new_df = spark.read.json(df2.rdd.map(lambda r: r.txt))
new_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- glossary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- GlossDiv: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GlossList: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- GlossEntry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Abbrev: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Acronym: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossDef: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSeeAlso: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- para: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSee: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossTerm: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SortAs: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```